# Sails.js modified header - cross domain

Tags: angularjs, cross-domain, sails.js

does anybody know where I can set a header in Sailsjs?

I have to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header that I can use my sails instance as API.

Currently I get this error if I try to send a request via $http.get in AngularJs

[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://acreasyURL.io/signin. Origin http://myhostOnMyMac.io:8000 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Any idea?

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, you don't have to set it manually.

Sails has some CORS functionality built in:

https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/bc148104378f1ad590a69220c25f60fe41a59790/config.cors.md

Comment: mmm strange. Could the reason https be? And the link get a 404

Comment: @Eike Corrected. Seems like they just merged something on top of the master branch several hours ago. Anyways, a link to a specific commit is better.

Comment: I got the cookie in the header but the browser doesn't set the cookie. Do I have something else to do to set the cookie? So I can see the cookie in the developer console in the header but the cookie is not set.

Comment: @Eike Sorry, but I'm hardly following. Could you please post it as a separate question and describe the problem more precisely? (Also, it's sort of StackOverflow rule to avoid long discussions in comments.) Thanks!